# how to change default precision in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe with floating type variables, i need to change the values of that variable to a n decimal places.  (dummy data)

```
prod_code  sales_avg
122       12332.234233
123       12212.234123
```

Currently i am doing the following :

```
prod_sales_avg=pd.DataFrame(weekly_sales.groupby(['prod_code']).agg({'weekly_sales':{'sales_avg':'mean'}}))
prod_sales_avg.columns=prod_sales_avg.columns.droplevel(0)
prod_sales_avg=prod_sales_avg.reset_index()
prod_sales_avg['sales_avg']=round(prod_sales_avg['sales_avg'],9)
```

i am getting the decimal places upto 6 places(i think that is default). I need to increase the decimal place to 9.but the above code does not work. Later i will be using this variable for comparison, so not looking for just **"display"** standpoint. The value should be stored as 9 decimal places. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: isn't [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) a better data type than float for fixed-precision calculations? panda's round refers to [numpy.around](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) which returns the infamously imprecise floats...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

*via Dataframe using [`Dataframe.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)*

```
prod_sales_avg.round({'sales_avg': 9})
```

*via Series using [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html#pandas.Series.round)*

```
prod_sales_avg['sales_avg'] = prod_sales_avg['sales_avg'].round(decimals=9)
```

Comment: somehow it did not work. for me I am still seeing 6 digits . do i need to change the default options ?. 
i entered pd.set_option('display.precision',10) at top then it works.

Comment: That could be the case. Just add `pd.set_option('precision',10)` after your `import` statements.